# return tuple result in async method .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an async method. This method get list of 10 row from database and getting total count of query result. Because I'm using for grid pagination. So, I'm using tuple which one element is List and other element is count of total number. But I can't return result because of compilation error. How i can do this?

```
public async Task<Tuple<List<IdNamePair>, int> GetStudents(QueryFilter queryObject)
{
    var query = studentEntity.Select(p => new IdNamePair
    {
        ID = p.ID.ToString(),
        Name = p.StudentNameSurname
    }).ToListAsync();

    int totalCount = await query.CountAsync();

    query = query.ApplyPaging(queryObject);//like Skip(20).Take(10)

    var students = query.ToListAsync();

    return await new Tuple<List<IdNamePair>, int>(students, totalCount); //ERROR
}
```

Comment: I think it should be Task<Tuple<List<IdNamePair>, int>> not Task<Tuple<List<IdNamePair>>, int> (mind >) in return type. Try that out

Comment: Thanks. Yes i edited while i write question. I edited. @Sham's solution worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ToListAsync` returns task, remove it to return IQueryable

```
public async Task<Tuple<List<IdNamePair>, int>> GetStudents(QueryFilter queryObject)
{
    var query = studentEntity.Select(p => new IdNamePair
    {
        ID = p.ID.ToString(),
        Name = p.StudentNameSurname
    });

    int totalCount = await query.CountAsync();

    var students = await query.ApplyPaging(queryObject).ToListAsync();

    return new Tuple<List<IdNamePair>, int>(students, totalCount); 
}
```

Answer (score 26):

You have some minor errors here.

**First**, the return type, the int is declared outside of the tuple. Add it inside.

**Then**, you have mixed the await keyword. Use it where you want to wait for async operations to finish.

Try it like this

```
public async Task<Tuple<List<IdNamePair>, int>> GetStudents(QueryFilter queryObject)
{
    var query = studentEntity.Select(p => new IdNamePair
    {
        ID = p.ID.ToString(),
        Name = p.StudentNameSurname
    });

    int totalCount = await query.CountAsync();

    query = query.ApplyPaging(queryObject);//like Skip(20).Take(10)

    var students = await query.ToListAsync();

    return new Tuple<List<IdNamePair>, int>(students, totalCount);
}
```

**Extra 1**: You could also use the shorter tuple declaration here

```
public async Task<(List<IdNamePair>, int)> GetStudents()
{
    ...
    return (students, totalCount);
}
```

**Extra 2**: In C# 7, You could also name the tuple items which brings more clarity to the consumer of the method

```
public async Task<(List<IdNamePair> Students, int TotalCount)> GetStudents()
{
    ...
    return (students, totalCount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MarcusHöglund . This code will work except "return (students, totalCount)" row.  Fabio's answer is worked.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir U ar correct. Updated the answer with some tips on what I refered to :)

Comment: Thanks @MarcusHöglund. This is also useful information for tuple usage.

Comment: For the record; The tuple type in Extra 2 called *Value Typed Tuple* and is slightly different than generic tuples

Comment: @Progressive thanks for the info. If u can please add that to the answer:-)

Answer (score 2):

You have used `await` keyword on wrong statement. This keyword is used with `asynchronous` method calls only.

Sample structure for `async` and `await` with given return type -

```
public async Task<Tuple<List<string>, int>> GetTupleResultAsync()
{
        List<string> listd = new List<string>() { "A", "A", "D", "E" };

        //Test code to await
        await Task.Run(() => "");

        return new Tuple<List<string>, int>(listd, listd.Count);
}
```

Try below modified code -

```
public async Task<Tuple<List<IdNamePair>>, int> GetStudents(QueryFilter queryObject)
{
  var query = studentEntity.Select(p => new IdNamePair
  {
    ID = p.ID.ToString(),
    Name = p.StudentNameSurname
  });

  int totalCount = await query.CountAsync();

  query = query.ApplyPaging(queryObject);//like Skip(20).Take(10)

  var students = await query.ToListAsync();

  return new Tuple<List<IdNamePair>, int>(students, totalCount); //ERROR
}
```

Comment: It give me error when i write like this. The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T> @Sham

Comment: This code cannot work, since `query` is of type `Task<List<T>>`, which doesn't have method `CountAsync`

Comment: Yes, you are right. That must AsQueryable instead of ToListAsync. @Fabio